# Create batches of IDs in BigQuery with fixed number of ids in each batch and sorted order

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to create a string aggregation of ids in batch groups from a table with 2 columns.

The source table has 2 columns with around 100k rows and I want to create 100 batches with about 1000 comma separated ids in each batch. They should be sorted in order of descending score.

Start table:

| ID | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 22334 | 725543 |
| 15432 | 65293 |
| 23456 | 17354 |
| 91274 | 2263 |

This is what I want to create:

| batch_grp | id_str (1000ids on each row. score is just for sorting and is left out |
| --- | --- |
| b00001 | 11223,33443,445566,22333,56566... |
| b00002 | 65293,33343,4674335,67656,8877887,55666... |
| b00003 | 17354,54,7777,55,333235,6656665... |

This is what I have which does create batches but just not equal size.

WITH x as(
SELECT ID, RANK() OVER(ORDER by SCORE DESC) as rank
FROM TABLESCORES
)

SELECT
REPLACE(LPAD(CAST(CAST(CEILING(rank / 100) as int64) as string),6),' ','0') as BATCH_GRP,

STRING_AGG(ID) as ID_STR
FROM x

GROUP BY BATCH_GRP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below approach

```
select div(pos - 1, 1000) + 1 as batch_grp, 
  string_agg('' || ID, ',' order by Score) as id_str
from (
  select *, row_number() over() pos
  from your_table
)
group by batch_grp
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks again Mikhail.

Comment: Works great. Thanks again Mikhail.